# Install psycopg2 for Anaconda Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda, psql

I have Anaconda Python 3.4, however whenever I run older code I switch to Anaconda Python 2.7 by typing "source activate python2". My issue is that I have psycopg2 installed for Anaconda Python 3.4, but not for Anaconda Python 2.7. When I run pip install psycopg2 (on Python 2.7) I get the following message:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:
    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

I am fairly new to programming and need help in:

```
1. Obtaining directory containing pg_config
2. Finding the path to Anaconda Python 2.7 
3. Adding pg_config to the PATH.
```

After I complete these steps I should be able to pip install Install psycopg2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need development system package for PostgreSQL which contains header files required to compile psycopg2 extension. For my CentOS 64 bit the command to install is:

```
yum install postgresql-devel.x86_64
```

but it depends on the OS - for Ubuntu that would be `apt-get install ...` - the name of the package varies slightly between distros.
Steps 2 and 3 should be unnecessary after you do this.

**EDIT:** For Mac OS that would be just:

```
brew install postgresql
```

as written [here](https://superuser.com/a/307836)

Comment: Since yum and apt-get are not on MAC OS, I tried:  brew install postgresql-devel.x86_64   ... no luck. Error: No available formula for postgresql-devel.x86_64

Answer (score 15):

If you have anaconda, you can sidestep some of these headaches.

You said you have the Anaconda distribution of python and a quick look at the [included packages](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) shows that psycopg2 is already there (although not in the installer). You can simply:

```
source activate python2
conda install psycopg2
```

This allows the conda installer to manage all of the binary dependencies.  Also makes it easier to upgrade.

If that does not work or there are reasons for not liking that package  (version issues?) then that is a different question.

Comment: this is the right way. pip seems to have a hard time knowing what to do with conda envs. repeated attempts to `pip install psycopg2-binary` in various ways (such as python package builds) failed, but just using the conda install did it.

Answer (score 2):

As OP is using Anaconda, if one wants to install `psycopg2`, open `CMD.exe Prompt` for the environment that one will be working on and run

```
conda install -c anaconda psycopg2

# or

conda install psycopg2
```

([Source](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/psycopg2))

If one wants to install `psycopg2-binary`, then use

```
conda install -c conda-forge psycopg2-binary

# or

conda install psycopg2-binary
```

([Source](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/psycopg2-binary))

---

**Notes:**

- If the above didn't work, consider using `pip` as follows:

  - `pip install psycopg2` ([Source](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/))
  - `pip install psycopg2-binary` ([Source](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/))

  Note, however, that `pip` doesn't manage dependencies the same way `conda` does and can, potentially, damage one's installation.

Answer (score 0):

env is the virtual environment created on Anaconda 
once env is activated, type this in the terminal :

```
conda install -n env [package]
```

eg.

```
$ conda install -n env psycopg2
```

After this type python to enter the Anaconda shell, and then type:

```
import psycopg2
```

If it shows no error, it has successfully been installed.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded anaconda and looks like i have access to pip3
`pip3 install psycopg2`